# How to block certain IP address from bitcoind or using ufw

Tags: bitcoind

Certain IP is brute forcing my node for rpc access. I tried ufw to deny that IP but did not work.
Looked for any black list conf entry or param to `bitcoind` and found none.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For ufw related issues: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rpcallowip` feature in your bitcoin.conf to whitelist IP addresses.

https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.10.0#rpc-access-control-changes

Comment: Note that by default, RPC access is only open to localhost.